Format richtextbox without selection
I want to change the formatting in a richtextbox in two ways:

text is selected => text should re-size. This works fine.
text is not selected, just a caret cursor is set between a text. => font-size should change for further writing. It shouldn't change the already existing text before => this don't work.

Example for my second requierement: My richtextbox got the text

stackoverflow

and the caret cursor is between stackover and flow like this:

stackover|flow

Now I need to change the fontsize on the current caret position for example to 20. On further writing I just want the text on this position displayed bigger. I don't want to change the current existing text. Like:

stackovercoolflow

cool should be in fontsize 20 now and stackover flow in default font size (like before)
I found a lot of answers but nothing of them helped me.
Most hints were:

Focus() on richtextbox
Use Selection.Start and Selection.End
Use an own method for 'SetFontSize'

But nothing of them worked for me...
Mostly I oriented myself on the following question wpf-richtextbox-fontface-fontsize
Currently I ended up with the followed code, but it only changes text-selection.
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <RichTextBox Height="300" Width="300" x:Name="MyRichTextBox" />
    <ComboBox Width="300" x:Name="cmbbx" SelectedIndex="1" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
</StackPanel>

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<double> Werte { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Werte = new ObservableCollection<double>();
            Werte.Add(4);
            Werte.Add(10);
            Werte.Add(20);
            Werte.Add(55);
            InitializeComponent();

            cmbbx.ItemsSource = Werte;
        }


        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var newSize = (double)cmbbx.SelectedValue;
            TextRange r = new TextRange(MyRichTextBox.Selection.Start, MyRichTextBox.Selection.End);
            r.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, newSize);
        }

    }
}

This just changes text-selection. There is no formatting when nothing is selected (just cursor is set). I am working with .net 5

In the question above the font size is changing for the selected text. This is the first case in your question. The second case is text is not selected, just a cursor is set and you don't describe clear enough what is your problem? What is a criteria should be used to define what part of a text in the RichTextBox need to be changed? Let say the current caret position defines the Start position. What is logic you are want to use to define the End position of the text fragment to be updated? To use the TextRange.ApplyPropertyValue() the both Start and End are required.

You can define criteria like "Change font size of the word on the current caret position" or  "Change font size of a text in the paragraph where the caret is located" etc. But some logic should be determined in your application.

Yes, text-selection works fine. I wan't to set the cursor between a word, changing the font size between the word and afterwards writing bigger (for example) between the word. I don't want to resize the whole word. I try to change my question more concrete.

Probably you want something like below:
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"        
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>            
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Width="60" x:Name="cmbbx" SelectedIndex="1" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>        
        <RichTextBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="rtb" AllowDrop="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Padding="2"                    
                     SelectionChanged="rtb_SelectionChanged"
                     TextChanged="rtb_TextChanged">
            <FlowDocument/>
        </RichTextBox>       
    </Grid>
</Window>

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            var Werte = new ObservableCollection<double> { 4, 10, 16, 20, 26, 55 };

            InitializeComponent();
            cmbbx.ItemsSource = Werte;
        }
       
        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!rtb.Selection.IsEmpty)
            {
                if (cmbbx.SelectedValue is double newSize)
                {                   
                    var range = new TextRange(rtb.Selection.Start, rtb.Selection.End);
                    range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, newSize);
                }
            }           
        }    

        // Use `TextChanged` event to apply the currently selected font size to the entered text
        private void rtb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Disable recursive calling this event handler 
            rtb.TextChanged -= rtb_TextChanged;

            foreach (var change in e.Changes)
            {
                if (cmbbx != null)
                {
                    TextPointer tp = rtb.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(change.Offset);
                    var range = new TextRange(tp, tp.GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Backward));
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(range.Text) && cmbbx.SelectedValue is double fontsize)
                    {
                        range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, fontsize);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Restore the event handler
            rtb.TextChanged += rtb_TextChanged;          
        }

        // The following `SelectionChanged` event handler is used to set a font size in the combobox 
        // depend on the current caret location.
        private void rtb_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            if (rtb.Selection is TextSelection selection)
            {
                if (selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty) is double fsize)
                {
                    foreach (var it in cmbbx.Items)
                    {
                        if ((double)it == fsize)
                        {
                            // The currently selected document fragment is containing font with size presented in the ComboBox
                            cmbbx.SelectedItem = it;
                            return;
                        }
                    }                  
                }
                // The currently selected document fragment contains fonts 
                // with different font sizes or the font size doesn't included to the the combobox 
                cmbbx.SelectedItem = null;
            }
        }
    }
}

I added some notes in the code above. Let me know if an additional descriptions are required.
